# Get text from an element with <br> on its composition, using Python Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, line-breaks

I'm pulling contact information (text) from a website and I can currently pull all the class data, using the following XPath syntax:

```
//*[@id="nomapdata"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]
```

Using this XPath expression for the element, I get the following text as the result:

```
Name
Title
Company Website
Phone Number
```

I want to pull each of these elements individually, but the problem is that, the data is separated by `<br>    </br>`, and I haven't had success on isolating each element.

Below is an example of the HTML structure:

```html
<div class="col-sm-d">
"
                  Name"
<br>
"
                              Title"
<br>
a href="www.website.com" target="_blank">http://www.website.com</a>
<br>
"

Phone: (555) 555-5555"
<br>
```

The only element I am able to isolate is the website.

How can I isolate each data in this scenario?

Comment: why not get them all as single string, and then split string by `<br>`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to get the list of text nodes as

```python
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="nomapdata"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]').text.split("\n")
```

If there are more text nodes after the phone number which you don't want to use:

```python
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="nomapdata"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]').text.split("\n")[:4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same locator but get the innerHTML instead of `.text`. This will get you all the HTML between the open and close `<DIV>` tags. Then you can split the resulting string by `<br>` and you will have all the desired pieces. From your sample HTML, it looks like you will probably want to `strip()` each piece to remove spaces and you will have to process/parse the link portion however you need.

```
s = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='nomapdata']/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]").get_attribute("innerHTML")
data = [item.strip() for item in s.split("<br>")]
```

`data` will now be an array of strings, e.g.

```
['Name', 'Title', '<a href="www.website.com" target="_blank">http://www.website.com</a>', 'Phone: (555) 555-5555']
```

You can then process whatever else you want/need to.

Answer (score -1):

First, get the elements:

```
var elements = _webDriver.FindElements(By.XPath(@"//*[@id='nomapdata']/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]"));
```

Second;

```
        foreach (var element in elements)
        {
            var temp = element.Split('\n');

            YourClass yourClass = new YourClass
            {
                Name = temp[0],
                Title = temp[1],
                CompanyWebsite = temp[2],
                PhoneNumber = temp[3],

            };

            yourList.Add(yourClass);
        }
```

Comment: That is definitely not Python.